# How to avoid for loops in r

Tags: r

I have a following data frame:

```
sent1 = data.frame(Sentences=c("abundant bad abnormal activity was     accomodative due to 2-face people","strange exciting activity was due to great 2-face people"), user = c(1,2))
```

And following pos and neg words.

```
pos = c("abound" , "abounds", "abundant", "exciting", "great")
neg = c("2-face","abnormal", "strange", "bad", "weird")
```

Then I have following code, which split unique words in each sentence and then match them with words in pos and neg dictionaries. Pos word is equal to 1 and neg word is equal to -1.

```
words = (str_split(unlist(sent1$Sentences)," "))

tmp <- data.frame()
tmn <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(sent1)) {
  for (j in 1:length(words[[i]])) {
    for (k in 1:length(pos)){
      if (words[[i]][j] == pos[k]) {

        tmn <- cbind(i,paste(words[[i]][j-1],words[[i]][j],words[[i]][j+1],sep=" "),1)
        tmp <- rbind(tmp,tmn)
      }
    }
    for (m in 1:length(neg)){
      if (words[[i]][j] == neg[m]) { 
        tmn <- cbind(i,paste(words[[i]][j-1],words[[i]][j],words[[i]][j+1],sep=" "),-1)
        tmp <- rbind(tmp,tmn)
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

If I have 1.000 sentences, it takes ~10 min... If I have 1.000,000 rows I can go for a holiday. Could you give me some advice, how to speed up this approach or how to avoid for loops...
Thank you very much in advance.

Required output:

```
user      matched word and it's neighbour             sentimentScore
1         abundant bad                                      1
1         abundant bad abnormal                            -1
1         bad abnormal activity                            -1
1         was accomodative due                              1
1         to 2-face people                                 -1
2         strange exciting                                 -1
2         strange exciting activity                         1
2         to great 2-face                                   1
2         great 2-face people                              -1
```

Comment: you put a very complicated code and hope we will read through this?Please put a desired output, the result you want from your example!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `str_count` function in stringr

```
library(stringr)
posReg <- paste(pos, collapse="| ")
str_count(sprintf("%s ", as.character(sent1$Sentences)), posReg)
```

This is generating a regular expression that matches any of your positives, followed by a space.  It then counts the number of matches of this regular expression in each of your sentences  In case you have a keyword at the end of the sentence, I add a space to ensure it matches.  It won't deal with punctuation etc, so you'll need to watch for that, but that wasn't part of the original question.

Comment: Resulted in [1] 0 2... what does it mean?

Comment: that there's zero instances of a positive word in the first row, 2 in the second row.  Your edit makes it clearer that you didn't just want to find number of matches, though.  You might want `str_locate_all`, but I'll think if there's a more direct way to your clarified question

Comment: I added required output above onto task.

Comment: You could try `ind <- na.omit(match(unlist(words), pos))` to get the indices of words that match, then `res <- data.frame(match=sprintf("%s %s %s", unlist(words)[ind-1], unlist(words)[ind], unlist(words)[ind+1]), sentiment=1)`  and `res$user <- rep(sent1$user, times=sapply(words, length))[ind]` to find the corresponding user.  Similar for negative.

Comment: If you use match, it returns only one match you have in dictionary... but what if you have more repeating words in sentence... you'll take only one word -> na.omit(match(unlist(words), pos))

Comment: sorry, use `ind <- which(unlist(words) %in% pos)` - the previous version was finding the index in 'pos', not 'words'.  The key idea is to match the words to your dictionary, not your dictionary to your words.  You'll need to correct for instances where the first or last word in a sentence matches, but shouldn't be too hard (e.g. add a null word to beginning and end of each words[[]])

Comment: I've tried it and that's the result:

Error in sprintf("%s %s %s", unlist(words)[ind - 1], unlist(words)[ind],  : 
  arguments cannot be recycled to the same length

Answer (score 0):

The main disdvantages with your code are: (1) you don't pre-allocate your results and, later, fill them; even if you're not sure about the final `length`/`nrow`/`ncol` etc, it's better to allocate extra space in advance. (2) you "read" `pos` and `neg` for every different word whereas you could use `match` (or its `%in%`); for example compare the performances:

```
x = sample(letters, 1e3, T); table = letters[c(1:3, 10, 15)]
identical(x %in% table, unlist(lapply(x, function(y) any(y == table))))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(x %in% table, unlist(lapply(x, function(y) any(y == table))))
#Unit: microseconds
#                                           expr      min        lq   median      uq       max neval
#                                   x %in% table   31.320   32.0165   33.408   34.80    42.457   100
# unlist(lapply(x, function(y) any(y == table))) 1310.925 1388.5290 1429.768 1536.43 45416.740   100
```

A way to address this problem could be:

```
tmp = lapply(strsplit(as.character(sent1$Sentences), " "), 
             function(x) {
                p = which(x %in% pos)
                n = which(x %in% neg)
                data.frame(word = c(unlist(lapply(p, function(i) paste0(c(x[i - 1], x[i], x[i + 1]), collapse = " "))),
                                    unlist(lapply(n, function(i) paste0(c(x[i - 1], x[i], x[i + 1]), collapse = " ")))),
                           val = rep(c(1, -1), c(length(p), length(n))))
             }) 
cbind(user = rep(sent1$user, sapply(tmp, nrow)), do.call(rbind, tmp))            
#  user                      word val
#1    1              abundant bad   1
#2    1     abundant bad abnormal  -1
#3    1     bad abnormal activity  -1
#4    1          to 2-face people  -1
#5    2 strange exciting activity   1
#6    2           to great 2-face   1
#7    2          strange exciting  -1
#8    2       great 2-face people  -1
```

Comment: If I use another data.frame, e.g.:

    sent1 = data.frame(Sentences=c("good printer for the money wireless setup was surprisingly easy",
                               "i love my samsung galaxy tabinch gb whitethis is the first tablet ive ever owedquot is just the right size for me i love the quality and picture perfect",
                               "the size is perfect and the weight is nice looks  great in white very user friendly except for the screen capture kinda funky but you can get an app for that love it overall"), user = c(1,2,3))

Comment: it resulted into:
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: Do you have any proposal, how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Martin : Sorry, I didn't have time earlier. I think the edit, now, takes into account zero matches int "pos"/"neg".